# Can't remove boxShadow from Material Top Bar Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using top tab navigation from React Native's navigation package, created with the `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` function. The tab bar has a box shadow on it by default, which I would like to disable. Here's my code for the tab screen config:

```
const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    "Test one": { screen: TestScreen1 },
    "Test two": { screen: TestScreen2 },
    "Test three": { screen: TestScreen3 },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      scrollEnabled: true,
      activeTintColor: '#000',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgb(180, 180, 180)',
      pressColor: 'orange',
      style: {
        boxShadow: 'none',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        numberOfLines: 1,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        //
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: 'orange',
        borderBottomWidth: 4,
      },
    },
  }
);
```

I'm trying to set the box shadow to `none` in the `style` object inside the `tabBarOptions`. This is where I would expect the styling for the box shadow to go. The `backgroundColor` property works fine, but `boxShadow` and certain other properties like `border` don't seem to register at all. Peculiarly, setting the `backgroundColor` property to an invalid color actually removes the `boxShadow`, but the tab bar defaults to white which I don't necessarily want to use. I've also tried changing the `boxShadow` inside the `tabStyle` object, which is the styling for the individual tabs as opposed to the entire tab bar, but got the same results. How to I get the desired effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to get the desired behavior by setting `elevation: 0` inside the `style` object. Apparently there's a default `elevation` value given to the tab bar, which automatically gives it a box shadow and overrides other box shadow related styles. This is an Android-only property and setting it to 0 gets rid of the shadow on Android, however on iOS there's a very thin border instead of a box shadow. That's a whole different question though. I will update this answer in case I find a solution for both platforms.

Answer (score 6):

```
tabBarStyle: { elevation:0 },
```

Put the elevation:0 inside tabBarStyle. That work for me, I hope it can help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

set the `elevation:0` inside `style`, after that use `indicatorStyle` property inside `tabBarOptions` to change the styling

Answer (score 1):

Try:

boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.0)'

Comment: I've already tried this and it gave me the same results as before.

Comment: Did you check it's parent's properties? It might also be possible if the parent has box-shadow properties which are set.

Answer (score 1):

Apply style `elevation:0, borderTopWidth:0` in tabBarOptions as follows:

```
<Tab.Navigator
   tabBarOptions={{
     style:{
      elevation:0,
      borderTopWidth:0
     }
   }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try  shadowOpacity: 0; or shadow-color: #000; not sure try it!

Comment: I've tried setting the shadow opacity/color but it made no change. It seems as if certain style properties are being ignored completely.

Comment: shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 } ? Could be another problem somewhere else. Check your layers or overflow hidden.. dunno

Answer (score 0):

Apply style `elevation:0` in `tabBarOptions` as follows:

```
<Tab.Navigator
   tabBarOptions={{
     style:{elevation:0}
   }}
>
```